# Following Recently Played Playlist

Tags: spotify

I am trying to create an app that takes some of the recently played songs from the users someone follows on Spotify, and turns them into a separate playlist. This way you wold have a playlist made up of songs that your friends recently listened to. Ideally it would refresh every 24 hours.

I found an endpoint that gets a current users recently played songs (https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/web-api-personalization-endpoints/get-recently-played/#play-history-object), but I'm not sure if this will enable me to get recently played songs from other users that the current user follows.

Can anyone tell me if this is feasible and, if so, how one might go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

that endpoint is only for getting the recently played tracks of the logged in user. This is to enforce that the app can only access data of users who have granted permission. What you **could** do is store the refresh token on every user you authenticate (which you will need to do anyway to fetch the recently played tracks every day without the user having to log in every time) and fetch recent tracks of users who have authorized your app that the current user is following.

Hope that helps!